# URL pathway is wrong

Tags: html, url, razor, umbraco

I'm working on a project were I want to add top links to the masterPage and each top-link to have its own navigation like this:
[image]

What I did was to include the top-links directly under the Content

[image]

The problem with this however, is that the URL pathway is wrong when selecting a menu under non-HomePage link

For example if I select For skolpersonal as a top-link and then select a menu and then a submenu, the URL pathway would be: *menu/submenu*
What I want it to be is: *for-skolpersonal/menu/submenu*
For some reason the URL "resets" every time I select a menu under a top-link.

**MasterPage:**

```
 <header>
        <div class="row col-md-12">
            <nav class="entry-links">
                <ul>
                    <li id="elever">
                        <a href="~/" title="För elever">För elever</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="skolpersonal">
                        <a href="/for-skolpersonal/" title="För skolpersonal">För skolpersonal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="ungdom">
                        <a href="/ungdom-och-elevdatabas/" title="Ungdom och elevdatabas">Ungdom och elevdatabas</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <a href="@home.Url">
                    <div class="brand" style="background-image:url('@(home.SiteLogo)?height=100&width=700&')"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 main-nav">
                <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="meny cbp-hrmenu col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    @{ Html.RenderPartial("MainNavigation"); }
                </nav>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="toggle" class="toggle">
            <a href="#" class="cross"><span></span></a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

**MainNavigation:**

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{ var home = CurrentPage.Site(); }

@if (home.Children.Any())
{



    @* Get the first page in the children *@
    var naviLevel = home.Children.First().Level;
    @* Add in level for a CSS hook *@
    <div class="linje"></div>
    <ul class="meny level-@naviLevel">
        @* For each child page under the home node *@
        @foreach (var childPage in home.Children)
{

    if (childPage.Children.Any())
    {

        <li class="dropdown has-child @(childPage.IsAncestorOrSelf(CurrentPage) ? "selected" : null)">
            @if (childPage.DocumentTypeAlias == "Huvudmeny")
            {
                <span>@childPage.Name</span>
                @childPages(childPage.Children)
            }
            else
            {
                <a href="@childPage.Url" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">@childPage.Name</a>
            }

            @helper childPages(dynamic pages)
{
            @* Ensure that we have a collection of pages *@

    if (pages.Any())
    {
        @* Get the first page in pages and get the level *@
        var naviLevel = pages.First().Level;

        @* Add in level for a CSS hook *@

    <ul class="meny dropdown-menu sublevel level-@(naviLevel)">
        @foreach (var page in pages)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a>

                @* if the current page has any children *@
                @if (page.Children.Any())
                {
                    @* Call our helper to display the children *@
                    @childPages(page.Children)
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    }   
}
        </li>            
    }

    else
    {
              <li class="@(childPage.IsAncestorOrSelf(CurrentPage) ? "selected" : null)">
                  <a href="@childPage.Url">@childPage.Name</a>
             </li>
            }   
        }
    </ul>
       <div class="linje col-md-12" ></div>
}
```

Is there a way to make the URL pathway to go as I want them to? *topmenu/menu/submenu*

I'm using Umbraco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include top level nodes in the path go to your **web.config** file and change the value of the `umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath` app setting from `true` to `false`.

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to look for a solution for days and now this solved it .